# Run javax.script.ScriptEngine with Python 3

Tags: java, javax.script

I want to call classes/functions written in `Python 3` from my Java library. For that, I tried to use `javax.script.ScriptEngine;`, but when I execute these lines:

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("python") ;
engine.eval("import sys") ;
engine.eval("print(sys.version)") ;
```

The python version loaded is 2.7 instead of the 3.6 version that I find (and need because the code I want to call is in Python 3.6) when executing the exact same lines into a terminal.

How can I load python 3.6 instead of 2.7?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: Unfortunately no :-( I decided to generate the python file and run it as a regular command